# Dit-on plutôt «je l’ai vu par son attitude », « je l’ai vu avec son attitude » ou « je l’ai vu de par son attitude »?

Tags: usage, choix-de-mot, syntaxe, formulation

Contexte.

Nicole n’était pas contente qu’on lui rende visite. Je l’ai vu par son attitude peu chaleureuse./ Je l’ai vu avec son attitude peu chaleureuse./ Je l’ai vu de par son attitude peu chaleureuse.

Si jamais aucune n’est correcte, n’hésitez pas à me faire savoir ce qui cloche, et à en donner la correction.

Merci

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La façon courant de connecter ces idées est d'utiliser la préposition « à ».

- Je l'ai vu **à** son attitude peu chaleureuse.

On peut aussi utiliser « par ».

- Je l'ai vu **par** son attitude peu chaleureuse.

« Avec » et « de par » ne son pas utilisés, le premier parce qu'il n'est pas idiomatique et le second parce qu'il n'est pas courant ; au lieu d'utiliser « de par  » dans ce contexte on utilise plutôt « du fait », ce qui est u synonyme de « de par ».

- Je l'ai vu **du fait de** son attitude peu chaleureuse.

Voici la fréquence des emplois considérés : [ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=l%27ai+vu+par%2Cl%27ai+vu+avec%2Cl%27ai+vu+de+par%2Cl%27ai+vu+%C3%A0&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=19&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cl%27%20ai%20vu%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cl%27%20ai%20vu%20avec%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cl%27%20ai%20vu%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cl%27%20ai%20vu%20par%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cl%27%20ai%20vu%20avec%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cl%27%20ai%20vu%20%C3%A0%3B%2Cc0).

« Avec » est plus propre à signifier le moyen matériel, la manière, l'accompagnement et d'autres nuances.

- Je l'ai vu avec des jumelles. (moyen) ♦ Je l'ai vu avec difficulté. (manière)